# which database supports to insert vietnamese characters?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I tried inserting Vietnamese characters into MySQL database through my java program. It is getting inserted but certain characters are being inserted as junk. And while trying to retrieve, i'm getting the same junk values in place of some characters. Can anyone tel me what should be done? Is there a problem in MySQL or is there any DB that supports these characters?

Answer (score 1):

Example of ‘junk’, and code?

In general you need to make sure:

1. your tables are created with UTF-8 collation on all text columns. This can be done at several levels: config `default-character-set=utf8`, db `CREATE DATABASE ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`, table `CREATE TABLE ... DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`, and column `column VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8`. After the initial creation you can only do it by `ALTER` on the columns; changing the default character sets won't change the column.
2. that your connection to the database is in UTF-8 encoding, by specifying `useUnicode=true` and `characterEncoding=UTF-8` properties in your connection string or properties. Ensure you have an up-to-date MySQL Connector as there have been grievous bugs here in the past.
3. that nothing else in your processing stream is mangling the characters before they get to the database connection, or on the way back out. Ensure you aren't using the default encoding anywhere because it is probably wrong. Setting the flag `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` may help with that as a temporary workaround, but you don't want to rely on it.

(And if part of your testing involves printing to the terminal, be aware that the Windows command prompt won't be able to do anything with UTF-8 so you will definitely see junk there.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there no problem to store vietnamese characters, but check mysql FAQ first:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-cjk.html